# How to use a Future as yew::callback::Callback

Tags: rust, yew

I have following callback which I'm registering to `onsubmit` event.

```rust
use gloo::net::http::Request;
use yew::prelude::*;

    let on_submit = Callback::from(async move |ev: FocusEvent| {
        ev.prevent_default();

        let res = Request::post("https://formsubmit.co/srineshnisala@gmail.com")
            .send()
            .await
            .unwrap();

        assert_eq!(res.status(), 200);
    });
```

However, I get following error when I use `async`

```
  --> src/pages/contact/contact.rs:26:36
   |
26 |       let on_submit = Callback::from(async move |ev: FocusEvent| {
   |  _____________________--------------_^
   | |                     |
   | |                     required by a bound introduced by this call
27 | |         ev.prevent_default();
28 | |
29 | |         let res = Request::post("https://formsubmit.co/srineshnisala@gmail.com")
...  |
34 | |         assert_eq!(res.status(), 200);
35 | |     });
   | |_____^ expected `()`, found opaque type
   |
  ::: /home/s1n7ax/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:72:43
   |
72 |   pub const fn from_generator<T>(gen: T) -> impl Future<Output = T::Return>
   |                                             ------------------------------- the found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
            found opaque type `impl Future<Output = ()>`
   = note: required for `yew::Callback<yew::FocusEvent>` to implement `From<[closure@src/pages/contact/contact.rs:26:36: 26:63]>`
```

Rust version:

```
rustc 1.66.0-nightly (01af5040f 2022-10-04)
```

package versions:

```
yew = "0.19.3"
yew-router = "0.16.0"
gloo = "0.7.0" # console log and stuff
hyper = "0.14.19" # http requests
```

How to use an async function as a callback in yew?

Comment: You can't. `from(impl Fn(I) -> O)` is the only way to construct a Callback. You have to either use block_on in the callback closure or use callback to register an action in an external async context, for example using a channel.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a `Callback` from an async closure but you can use [`wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen_futures/fn.spawn_local.html) to run a `Future` on the current thread:

```rust
use gloo::net::http::Request;
use yew::prelude::*;

    let on_submit = Callback::from(move |ev: FocusEvent| {
        ev.prevent_default();
        wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
            let res = Request::post("https://formsubmit.co/srineshnisala@gmail.com")
                .send()
                .await
                .unwrap();

            assert_eq!(res.status(), 200);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
`Callback::from(impl Fn(In) -> Out)` is the only way to construct a non-noop `Callback`.
You have to either use `block_on` to perform an async operation synchronously, or use callback only to register an action in an external async context, for example using a channel.